# Linked list loops endlessly

Tags: c

I'm writing a simple linked list implementation for the sake of learning. My linked list consists of `node` structures that contain an `int` value and a pointer to the next node. When I run my code, it loops endlessly even though it should terminate when it reaches a NULL pointer. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
  int value;
  struct node *next_node;
};

struct node * add_node(struct node *parent, int value)
{
  struct node child;
  child.value = value;
  child.next_node = NULL;

  parent->next_node = &child;
  return parent->next_node;
}

void print_all(struct node *root)
{
  struct node *current = root;

  while (current != NULL) {
    printf("%d\n", current->value);
    sleep(1);
    current = current->next_node;
  }
}


int main()
{
  struct node root;
  root.value = 3;

  struct node *one;
  one = add_node(&root, 5);
  print_all(&root);
}
```

Comment: How far did you step thru this in the debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior: you are setting a pointer to a locally allocated `struct` here:

```
struct node child;
child.value = value;
child.next_node = NULL;

parent->next_node = &child;
return parent->next_node;
```

Since `child` is on the stack, returning a parent pointing to it leads to undefined behavior.

You need to allocate `child` dynamically to make it work:

```
struct node *pchild = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
// In production code you check malloc result here...
pchild->value = value;
pchild->next_node = NULL;

parent->next_node = pchild;
return parent->next_node;
```

Now that you have dynamically allocated memory, do not forget to call `free` on each of the dynamically allocated nodes of your linked list to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Can you explain your last sentence further? Also, when I declare `struct node root` in the `main()` function, is `root` locally allocated or is it accessible outside of the `main()` function?

Comment: @fbonetti Since `main` is the last function on the stack, you can use anything that you declare there in virtually any context. The `free` function needs to be called on every pointer that you allocated with `malloc`. You need to write a function `free_all` similar to `print_all` that goes through the list, and frees each node that it sees. Keep in mind that it is illegal to free the node allocated in `main`, so you would want to call `free_all(root.next)`.

Answer (score 4):

`add_node` returns a pointer to a local variable which immediately goes out of scope and may be reused by other functions.  Attempting to access this in `print_all` results in undefined behaviour.  In your case, it appears the address is reused by the `current` pointer, leaving `root->next_node` pointing to `root`.

To fix this, you should allocate memory for the new node in `add_node`

```
struct node * add_node(struct node *parent, int value)
{
    struct node* child = malloc(sizeof(*child));
    if (child == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    child->value = value;
    child->next_node = NULL;

    parent->next_node = child;
    return child;
}
```

Since this allocates memory dynamically, you'll need to call `free` later.  Remember not to try to free `root` unless you change it to be allocated using `malloc` too.